# Add new dependencies in IntelliJ Idea 12 Ultimate project using maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

After I tried unsuccessfully to add ehcache dependencies manually in a hibernate project using IntelliJ Idea , I decided to use maven and I added maven framework support to the project.Now I have an existing pom.xml file and I want to add the pom (with its dependencies) from this location (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/4.1.9.Final/).
How do I do that?
Can I have more than one pom.xml file in a project?
Thank you.

Here is the current pom.xml file I am using :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>HibernateProject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Now I am getting the following error :

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open only one IDEA project per IDEA window. But a Maven project can be made of [multiple modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html), each one having its own `pom.xml`. You can also import multiple Maven projects in the same IDEA project.

If you have an existing Maven project, just open the root `pom.xml` using `File > Open` and IDEA will ask you if it should be [opened as a Maven project](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_and_importing_Maven_projects) (providing you have enabled the Maven plugin in IDEA). When you make changes to a `pom.xml`, IDEA will suggest you to reimport the project, thus adding/removing libraries to synchronize the IDEA project with the Maven project.

To add a dependency to hibernate, add this code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Adding maven framework support after project creation, seems to create more problems.Do you believe that I should create a maven project from the first step of project creation wizard in IntelliJ Idea?What is your experience?

Comment: I've added the two dependencies you suggest (you can check the edited original post) but I am getting an error.

Comment: @ben75 I never said you can't have only one pom.xml per window, I said that you can have one maven project containing multiple pom.xml (modules).

Comment: yes, but what I'm saying is that you an have more than one maven project per window: you can have 2 (or more) totally independant maven project (single or multi module) in one IDEA window (see my answer)

Comment: @skiabox IDEA and maven works very well together. The only step I always do when I start to work with a new maven project under IDEA is to open it by choosing it's pom.xml file (instead of adding maven support later)

Comment: I created a maven project from scratch and then I added hibernate support.The interesting thing is that I am getting the same exact error : Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Comment: One problem that I have is that I have no resources folder!

Comment: I've created a resources folder manually and I putted hibernate.cfg.xml in there.Now I am getting the following error : Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]

Comment: @ben75 I clarified my answer to remove the confusion between multiple Maven/IDEA projects :). skiabox could you post the full stacktrace in your original question please? Also update the posted pom.xml if it has changed.

Comment: This site helped me put all things in order and solved all my problems : http://mvnrepository.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple maven project in one IDEA window.

You can always open a project from it's pom.xml file (if it's a multi-module project: all sub modules will be included automatically in your IDEA window).

When you have a maven project (single module or multi-module) open, you can go to the tab "Maven Project" (usually on the right side of the window). In this tab you can click on the "Green +" button : "Add maven project" and then browse to another pom.xml and select it: all the modules define in this other pom.xml will be **added** to your current IDEA window.