# osgi projects with several poms in intellij idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, osgi, multi-project

I have two maven projects with 2 poms (type). Some components from project 1 are depending on projects 2. Almost all components (maven) are osgi components.

The question is: since IntelliJ IDEA does not support multi-projects it is impossible to open two projects at the same time in one IDE instance.

Then, I believe, I'm going to have an issue to deploy my osgi components (they have are associated to OSGI Facets in IDE) to my osgi container from IDE (because it supposed to be handled by IDE, using those facets while deploying component to the osgi server, and if I can not see project 2 in my IDE then it could not handle it.. in terms of deploying and ide integration).

For example if I open two IDEs with project 1 in one, and project 2 in second ide, then if I change something in project 2 (1 depends on 2) .. should I configure the same (one) osgi sever in both IDEs, and deploy it separately?

Does someone have the same project structure, and what is the way to work with this in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have only one IDEA project per window, but a single project can contain multiple Maven projects, see [my answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15382685/500478).

Open your first pom.xml via `File > Open` to create a new IDEA project, then open the `Maven Projects` view on the right, click on the green plus to add your second Maven project, and voila!

Once this is configured, you can create a new run/debug configuration which will deploy both artifacts on the same tomcat instance.

Comment: that's true. I even did not know. Will see how it goes with osgi.. then will update this question. latter on.